# how to add a condition like a greater than equal to in filter search in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-resource, vue-select

Hi every one i am going to build a real-estate application 
i want to add a condition in Bedrooms filter function like a "greater than equal "

Eg:- if i select 2 on Bedroom list i want to filter greater than equal 2 Bedrooms properties

How can i do this

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      blogs: [],
      minbed: this.$route.params.bed,
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.$http.get("https://test.json").then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      this.blogs = data.body;
    });
  },
  computed: {
    filteredList() {
      const { blogs, search, UnitType } = this;
      return this.blogs
        .filter(blog => blog.Bedrooms.includes(this.minbed))
  }
}
```

```html
<select
  v-model="minbed"
  id="formInput202"
  class="form-control"
  value="MaxBedrooms"
>
  <option>Max.Bedrooms</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>ST</option>
</select>
```

Comment: the exports belongs to your `<select>`?

Comment: yes the exports Belongs to <select>

Comment: Can you try to pass the `MaxBedrooms` value as an object like `['1','2']` for select 2, `includes` will accept multiple values.

Comment: its not working

Comment: Why does this have the vue-select tag when it's not asking about https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`includes` method is not working in this case. Only accepts string as the param (Ref-[Link1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)).

The inline callback function will sort out this case,

Check the below code.

```
filteredList() {
    const { blogs, search, UnitType } = this;
    var MaxBedroomsVal = this.minbed;
    return this.blogs.filter( function (blog) { 
        return blog.Bedrooms >= MaxBedroomsVal;
    })
}
```

Ref: [Link2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Filtering_out_all_small_values)